# How to show default url if variable value is empty in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, ternary-operator, laravel-blade

I know that for a normal variable I can use something like `{{ $vid->shares ? : '0' }}` to show default information in Laravel 5.7 blade files.

Now I need to show image source, which I am doing like `<img src="{{ url($vid->thumb_file) }}">` this works fine until I hit a empty value.

is there anything to avoid such case by adding a default fallback image URL? Or "if else" is only a better solution?

Something like `{{ url($vid->thumb_file) ?: url('/images/video-thumbnail.png') }}` which is not working.

Comment: Check it like: `$vid->thumb_file ? url($vid->thumb_file) : url('/images/video-thumbnail.png')`

Comment: Yes, that works. `<img src="{{ $vid->thumb_file ? url($vid->thumb_file) : url('/images/video-thumbnail.png') }}" alt="" class="img-fluid">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like below:

```
<img src="{{ $vid->thumb_file ? url($vid->thumb_file) : url('/images/video-thumbnail.png') }}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```

This is as same as Ternary Operator you used above: `{{ $vid->shares ?: '0' }}`

You can also check it in your controller, like:

```
if (file_exists(public_path() . '/images/' . $vid->image)) {
    $img = $vid->image;
} else {
    $img = '/images/video-thumbnail.png';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this way:**

```
{{ isset($vid->thumb_file) ? $vid->thumb_file : url('/images/video-thumbnail.png') }}

<img src="{{ isset($vid->thumb_file) ? $vid->thumb_file : url('/images/video-thumbnail.png') }}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```